# Formula field based on Master-Detail relationship

Tags: administration, custom-object

I have a custom object called Sports, where I have a master-detail relationship with Contacts.  I would like to build a formula field on Sports that references a field on the contact (specifically, gender).  When I go to build the formula field, I do not have Contact as an option.  Is there something special I need to do to make that available?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should just be able to do something like `Contact__r.Gender__c` right in your formula field, assuming the name of the master-detail relationship is `Contact__c`

Comment: You can find Contact__r and other related fields if you switch to the "Advanced Formula" tab in the formula editor.